# How to set as selected first value by default from a select list in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have create select list with following code. it is working fine. but, it does selected by default last value(option). How to set as selected first value by default from a select list in Twig

**My Code:**

```
<select name="my_item">
    <option value="3" {% if my_item == '3' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>3</option>
    <option value="4" {% if my_item == '4' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>4</option>
    <option value="5" {% if my_item == '5' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>5</option>
    <option value="6" {% if my_item == '6' %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>6</option>
</select>
```

**I got:**

```
<select name="my_item">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6" selected="selected">6</option>
</select>
```

**I Want:**

```
<select name="my_item">
    <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That should only happen if `my_item == '6'`. Selects always show the first option unless another option is _specifically_ set as selected. (and it doesn't actually set `selected="selected"`). Try to echo the `my_item`-value, and you will most likely see that it is 6. If you _still_ want the first to be selected, then remove your seleced-logic (it-statements).

Comment: In your html code you have `selected="selected"` attribute for multiple elements. Keeping the value for your selected option will result the answer you seek.

Comment: @CodeMonkey OP does not have multiple selected statements in there

Comment: @DarkBee aah yes. It was my mistake. Sorry. :)

Comment: I guess the OP gave up?

Comment: Or he found out that his variable was indeed holding a value

Answer (score 0):

I suspect like in the comments above the variable of `my_item` is set to `6`. You can check this in Twig and the debug environment by using:

```
{{ dump(my_item) }}
```

and that should print out the value. You use the `app_dev.php` URL, so if your URL was:

http://example.com/

Then for the debug URL you would use:

http://example.com/app_dev.php

Here is the working Twigfiddle showing the code working with `my_item` set to `3`: https://twigfiddle.com/ri31vn